# How to add a List<> data to a List<> variable using EF Core C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a CRUD Web API and I am just following this [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio). In my case, I have `two models`:

**`First_Model.cs`**:

```
// i removed other unnecessary data
public string Id { get; set; }
public IList<Second_Model> Second_Models {get; set;} = new List<Second_Model>();
```

**`Second_Model.cs`**:

```
// i removed other unnecessary data
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Just like in the tutorial, it will statically add a default value of the collection, so I want to add `List<Second_Model>` into `Second_Models`

Here's what I tried in my `First_ModelController.cs`

```
_context.First_Models.Add(
    new First_Model {
        Id = "default_id",
        Second_Models = new List<Second_Model>() {
            new List<Second_Model>().Find(p => p.Id == "default_id")
            // given that Second_Model also has default_id
        };
    }
);
```

However, this set of codes will return this error:

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key
```

Comment: `....Find(p => p.Id == "default_id")` should not be empty

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour I also have static default value in my `Second_Model`

Answer (score 0):

Statically creating a list of objects would look more like this:

```
....
Id = "default_id",
Second_Models = new List<Second_Model>() {
    new Second_Model() { Id = "<your second model ID 1>", OtherProperty = <value> },
    new Second_Model() { Id = "<your second model ID 2>", OtherProperty = <value> },
}
```

However, if you are want to add them directly to the context, you would do something similar to:

```
_context.Second_Models.Add(
    new Second_Model() {
        Id = "<your second model ID 1>",
        OtherProperty = <value>,
    }
);
... repeat ...
```

That does not associate the second_model with the first_model though.
You might need to read more about defining foreign keys on EF models so make this all join together, because I don't think the tutorial includes anything related to that.

Comment: I have the `Second_Model` context and I have my `Second_Model.Id` having the `[Key]` attribute. What do I still need so I can use `Second_Model.FindAsync(id)` in my `Second_Models = new List<Second_Model>() { find_async_here }` in my first context